# expand.grid equivalent to get pandas data frame for prediction in Python

Tags: python, r, pandas

In R can quite easily do:

```
expand.grid(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5))
```

to get a data frame:

[image]

I think something like this may work in Python:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid

param_grid = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5]}
expanded_grid = ParameterGrid(param_grid)
```

but being a converter from R to Python I would not know if this the best way and how to get a pandas data frame, ultimately to be used for predictions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas we have `MultiIndex`

```
d =  {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5]}
out = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(d.values(),names=d.keys()).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[58]: 
   a  b
0  1  4
1  1  5
2  2  4
3  2  5
4  3  4
5  3  5
```

or simple with `itertools`

```
import itertools
out = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*d.values()),columns=d.keys())
Out[62]: 
   a  b
0  1  4
1  1  5
2  2  4
3  2  5
4  3  4
5  3  5
```

Answer (score 1):

One option which might be faster as the data size increases is [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

jn.expand_grid(others=param_grid).droplevel(level = 1, axis = 'columns')

   a  b
0  1  4
1  1  5
2  2  4
3  2  5
4  3  4
5  3  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the similar as you do in `R` with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.base import c, expandgrid
>>> expandgrid(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5))
        a       b
  <int64> <int64>
0       1       4
1       1       5
2       2       4
3       2       5
4       3       4
5       3       5
```